# Building open source project(Mumble) in Qt via CMake on Windows

Tags: qt, cmake

I'm attempting to build [Mumble](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble) on my Windows 10 PC in Qt, and I'm running into some issues (I think I'm just a bit lost on some of the Qt, CMake, and build lingo). I've installed all of the required Qt packages through VCPKG, and I've built the program with *almost* no issues through the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019"...

[Here is the build documentation that Mumble provides.](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/blob/master/docs/dev/build-instructions/build_static.md)
I believe what's got me particularly confused is the CMake process. After getting the necessary packages installed, the Mumble instructions have you run the following `cmake -G` command.

```
cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static-md" "-Dstatic=ON" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Users\Skewb\Documents\repos\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake" "-DIce_HOME=D:\Users\Skewb\Documents\repos\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static-md" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" ..
```

Followed by the actual "build" command:

```
cmake --build .
```

From what I can tell,  there's no place for me  to input the `cmake -G` command in the "Build Settings" page. Here's where I've attempted to input it. I've been through the errors below, but I think my lack of understanding of `cmake --build` and `cmake -G` has made looking at these files unnecessary.
[image: d61f7e79-9437-451e-a59a-0a1bb1717b10-image.png]

If I've somehow gotten that correct (I haven't), here's the error I'm getting. It's unable to find the "Ice" directory, but I've specified it in that command.

```
-- Qt5 component found: Widgets | Version: 5.15.2
CMake Error at cmake/pkg-utils.cmake:87 (message):
  Ice component not found: Ice
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/murmur/CMakeLists.txt:267 (find_pkg)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/skewb/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-CfECuA/qtc-cmake-Kjqhpyja/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/skewb/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-CfECuA/qtc-cmake-Kjqhpyja/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake process exited with exit code 1.
Elapsed time: 00:55.
```

I've also gone through [these instructions](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-cmake.html) and found the "CMake generator" option in the "Kits" settings, but I don't see anywhere to change the options you feed it:
[image: qt kits settings]

I think I'm conflating a bunch of terms and their uses in the Mumble documentation vs. Qt including, but not limited to:

- Build
- Make
- Run
- Clean

Any help understanding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that "`<vcpkg dir>` is a **placeholder** for your prepared build environment vcpkg setup". So, your `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` and `Ice_HOME` shound't contain `<vcpkg dir>` *literally* but instead contain **actual** directory with your vcpkg environment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Ok, I've put the proper path into Qt, but I'm still getting the same error (that the "Ice" component cannot be found). I'm not supposed to put the generator call and options in the "build" call am I?

Comment: Have you actually installed Ice via vcpkg, as the documentation describes?

Comment: Yes, an I can build the entire project properly through the x64 dev console without issue. I'm encountering the issue now when I'm attempting to build it in Qt.